# Increase body limit with nestjs & fastify

Tags: nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify

My main.ts looks like this :

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { Logger } from 'nestjs-pino';
import { processRequest } from 'graphql-upload';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const adapter = new FastifyAdapter();
  const fastifyInstance = adapter.getInstance();
  fastifyInstance.addContentTypeParser('multipart', (request, done) => {
    request.isMultipart = true;
    done();
  });

  fastifyInstance.addHook('preValidation', async (request: any, reply) => {
    if (!request.raw.isMultipart) {
      return;
    }
    request.body = await processRequest(request.raw, reply.raw);
  });
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    adapter,
    { bufferLogs: true },
  );
  app.useLogger(app.get(Logger));
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(parseInt(process.env.SERVER_PORT || '3000', 10), '0.0.0.0');
}

bootstrap();
```

According to the [fastify doc](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#bodylimit) the body limit is 1MiB by default, however I want it to be larger. So I tried like this :
`const adapter = new FastifyAdapter({ bodyLimit: 124857600 });` but I still get the same problem with my payload being too large.

Comment: Who is `processRequest` function? Does it apply any additional limit?

Comment: It is from graphql-upload
`import { processRequest } from 'graphql-upload';`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this when you are creating the app

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
AppModule,
new FastifyAdapter({ bodyLimit: 10048576 }),
```